# array to image using np.full in opencv?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am new to opencv and I was just wondering if I can make a image using numpy array.
First I just made a simple black image using np.zeroes ->

```
import numpy as np
img = np.zeros([512,512,3])

cv.imwrite('color_img.jpg', img)
cv.imshow("image", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This displays a black image.
So I wanted to try out this with some different values using `np.full()`

Code->

```
import numpy as np
img = np.full([512, 512, 3], 0)

cv.imwrite('color_img.jpg', img)
cv.imshow("image", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

I first tried `np.full()` with other values than zero but it wasn't working then I tried the
same with `0`, but it still doesn't work.

This shows a window which instantly disappears, why?
Both are same arrays so why one shows and other not?
I checked the documentation of both `np.zeros()` and `np.full()`, if they
both return the same thing, then what is the error here.
Any explanation will be helpful.

I am trying to display a numpy array as image.
I was expecting `np.zeros()` and `np.full()` to work same but they didn't.

Comment: I have checked the output of the `np.zeros([512,512,3])`, it's an array of `float64`. But the output of the `np.full([512, 512, 3], 0)` is an array of `int32`. What if you change `np.full([512, 512, 3], 0)` to `np.full([512, 512, 3], 0.)` ?

Comment: Use `dtype` to specify the type of image you need: np.int8, np.uint8, np.float32...
For example:
`img = np.full([512, 512, 3], 0, dtype=np.uint8)`

Comment: yeah it's working, after changing the dtype of np.full() to float64/32 or unit8 it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the ***data type*** of both the arrays. (As pointed out in comments.)

The **dtype** of np.zeros() is **float64** while the **dtype** of np.full() is **int32**.
So, it's better to specify dtype while doing such things.

eg->
(array of zeros using np.full())

```
import numpy as np
img = np.full([512,512,3], 0, dtype=np.float64)
cv.imshow("image", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: `uint8`. range: 0 to 255. it is common to use, cheap to calculate with, takes the least space, and is recommended in general unless floats make more sense for your calculation. -- if using a float type, the range *for imshow* is 0.0 to 1.0 but the range for imwrite is still 0 to 255.